# Print all elements of the XPATH in PYTHON

Tags: android, python, xpath, uiview

I am trying to print elements of xpath:

```
elements = self.driver.find_elements((By.XPATH('//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.VideoView[1]')))
    print(elements)
```

However it comes up with outcome:

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Can anyone help me out with that, please?

Comment: If you remove then, the outcome is exactly the same. ALready tried this

Answer (score 0):

In `Python` `By.XPATH` is not a method (like in `Java`), but a simple string- `"xpath"`. You don't have to pass your locator as argument to `By.XPATH()`. Use below line instead

```
self.driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.VideoView[1]')
```

that is the same as

```
self.driver.find_elements("xpath", '//android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.widget.FrameLayout[1]/android.view.ViewGroup[1]/android.widget.VideoView[1]')
```